# scala.MatchError: null on scala

Tags: scala

I am getting the following error ..
scala.MatchError: null

Is there something wrong with my code ? And if so, how do I fix it ?

```
val a : Option[String] = {
  company.customUrl match {
    case Some(a) => company.a
    case None => null
  }
}

val b :Option[String] = {
  company.b match {
    case Some(b) => company.b
    case _ => null
  }
}

val c : Option[Long] = {
  company.c match {
    case Some(c) => Option(company.c.get.toLong)
    case _ => null
  }
}
```

Comment: Which one is throwing the error? Are all these fields of type `Option[T]`?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense. Post all the relevant stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The return types of `a,b,c` are all `Option`, but the raw type `null` in every second case is not. Try to return `None` instead.

`a` second case should catch all with `_`

`b` can also be simplified to `val b :Option[String] = company.b`

Answer (score 1):

In your first case, you must have a null value for `customUrl`:

```
scala> (null: Any) match { case Some(x) => x ; case None => ??? }
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 29 elided
```

It's considered better to wrap nullable values in Option as soon as possible and not to unwrap them. In particular, don't set Options to null.

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is meant to completely avoid `null`. Something that is `Option` should never be `null`; instead, it should be `None`. Therefore, you should not be doing this strange dance:

```
val a: Option[String] = company.customUrl match {
  case Some(a) => company.a
  case None => null
}
```

Just `val a = company.customUrl` will do.

This is also likely the cause of the `MatchError`. One or more of `company.customUrl`, `company.b`, or `company.c` is `null`, due to some other piece of your code.

Reiterating: ***`Option` should never be `null`.*** Furthermore, in Scala, always try to avoid `null` and prefer `Option`.